# Loss of reputation points on downvoting for the down-voter should be proportional to their reputation

Tags: feature-request, downvotes

I have noticed that people downvote a question which is not of such bad standards also a lot, sometimes to -6 or -7. Is this not unfair to people who are just starting out (in career or in a subject)?

Actually the root of the problem lies somewhere else - penalty for downvoting is very less.

The penalty for downvoting should be harsher. In fact the quantum of reputation which is reduced on a downvote should increase with every 10 multiple of reputation of the downvoter. For eg. -2 for folks of reputation 100, -4 for those with reputation 1000, -8 for people with reputation 10000, -16 for folks with reputation -10000 and so on.

Lastly, I would like to mention that I am not against maintaining quality - quality of questions and answers is required else stackoverflow loses its edge. So, downvoting should be there. But it should be more accountable.

Comment: Unless high-rep-users downvotes would count at least that much more, you are just killing the usefulness of scores for quickly assessing whether they are worth reading. Wait, that was your plan, and unaccountable upvotes were only the first step? Ok, carry on then.

Comment: Do you have a concrete example? I mean, not this question.... because, just check the related column here on the right ----> You are proposing a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate.... it's always nice to research a bit before posting a Question.

Comment: Lol. Your post is getting downvoted because the change you propose is absolutely poisonous to SO's quality, and something along those lines is proposed by those who fail to try to learn from the past **by searching** at least once every week. Seeing justified rejection of their less than stellar proposal as verification is also typical.

Comment: Dhruv, you're the one proposing modifications to the system. Reading what was discussed before would greatly enhance your argument.

Comment: @DhruvRaiPuri: There are lots of proposals for curtailing or abolishing downvoting, and making it more "accountable". Though I doubt there's an *exact* match to yours (you found a way to geld all experienced users which I'm not sure anyone thought might be a good idea yet), that doesn't matter.

Comment: Please, assume the default reasons when you receive a downvote without explanations; just hover the downvote button: *"This question does not show any **research effort**; it is unclear or not useful* - (bold is mine)

Comment: @DhruvRaiPuri you may be intersting to know that [Voting is different on Meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).  You proposed a feature, some people may just be disagreeing, although I imagine a fair share probably for the reasons '@brasofilomentioned earlier

Comment: @psubsee2003 - That is the most logical answer I have gotten till now on this thread. Thanks for the same.

Comment: brasofilo and deduplicator - don't know your real names... sorry for any misgivings... I got the answer which I was looking for... will delete the question in about 5 minutes...

Comment: @DhruvRaiPuri you can't, it has an upvoted answer.

Comment: Oh, don't worry. By now it is so downvoted, hardly anyone will find it anymore. Also, meta-downvotes don't have any consequences beside that.

Comment: @DhruvRaiPuri for Meta participation, you may be interested in reading [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying)

Comment: Nothing wrong with going against the flow, unless you're going against the flow by way of an accusatory tone. If you want to be taken seriously, I suggest laying off with the strong accusations and the name-calling. That, by the way, was what I meant by [salty](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/salty) - I never said anything about newcomers. I'd gladly listen to a newcomer if only they contained their frustration and channeled it into constructive discussion.

Comment: So you're setting out to get people to not downvote bad answers.  In what world would that ever be a good thing?  We have a serious problem of people *not* downvoting bad answers when *we want them to*.  What we really need to be doing is figuring out how to better encourage people to actually downvote (because now many don't) when they come across a bad post.

Comment: @CodeCaster are you sure about that title edit?  Post seems to be saying the exact opposite.

Comment: @Dhruv Rai Puri: Thanks, that is something very few people ever do. Most just up and leave in an emotional fit. Your question remains contestable, but at least now it is a somewhat amicable disagreement.

Comment: OK, time to open sockpuppets specifically for downvoting.

Answer (score 34):

> This clearly shows that the power of points and authority is going to the head of many folks.

Your question shows nothing because you have no proof. You can't prove that the people 'pouncing' are mainly high rep users and you don't show any proof of undeserved down votes. In fact, your question proves that those posts **do** deserve down votes because you're talking specifically about answers that are *wrong*.

You can't say that you're not against maintaining quality when you're arguing against down voting posts that are flat out incorrect.

> Is this not unfair to people who are just starting out...

No, it's not unfair to hold all posts to the same quality standards, regardless of the poster. How would allowing new users to post low quality, off topic, or incorrect posts be fair to the rest of the community?

Comment: I believe it should be added (as another point for why it isn't unfair) that as it's impossible for reputation to fall under 1, bad first posts by newcomers don't actually have any long term negative effect